# Wrong object position after unity import

Tags: unity, .fbx

I created a 3d model which consists of 3 objects:

[image]

When i import this 3d model to Unity, one of these three objects is in the wrong position:

[image]

When i export the 3d model i have `!EXPERIMENTAL! Apply Transform` checked.

If i uncheck `!EXPERIMENTAL! Apply Transform` then the position is correct, but the rotation of the model is wrong (in Unity).

Answer (score 2):

I believe in Unity Y-axis face upwards, while in Blender it's Z-axis. So it makes sense if your object rotates that way (thought it depends what options you use while exporting from Blender, there are options for Forward and Up axis). I would check rotations on all 3 objects in Blender and apply them if they are not at 0 (Object->Apply->Rotation).